# Tag [svelte] should be syntax highlighted as lang-html

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

[svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svelte) is a web framework where components are expressed with HTML syntax. Here's an example of what Svelte code looks like from [their website](https://svelte.dev/):

```
<script>
    let count = 0;

    function handleClick() {
        count += 1;
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Clicked {count} {count === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
```

But the [svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svelte) tag doesn't have any syntax highlighting hint, so questions tagged with that look kinda drab. The syntax highlighting hint should be `lang-html`:

```html
<script>
    let count = 0;

    function handleClick() {
        count += 1;
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Clicked {count} {count === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
```

That looks better!

Comment: Surprisingly it does. Svelte is one of those multilingual frameworks, it's both javascript (or typescript) and html often in the same file so I wouldn't expect lang-html to work this well.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Svelte, but if the JavaScript is consistently in `<script>` tags, then the `lang-html` highlighter will highlight it just fine; it will process such code with the JS highlighter. Can't vouch for TypeScript, however.

Comment: @Gimby - Syntax highlighters for HTML have long had to contend with embedded `script` and `style` elements, and highlighting them decently is a goal for those tools. If you look at the example of HTML highlighting [here](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/) (if it's not already picked, pick "Common" from the list; HTML is at the top), it has surprisingly little HTML in it but does have JavaScript and CSS. I can't find anything stating it baldly, but given that Highlight.js supports JavaScript and CSS, I suspect they switch to those for the contents of those elements.

Comment: Same thing happens with Vue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder then I retract my statement that it is surprising :) Svelte is then perfectly designed to be highlighted by lang-html.